# with golang, how to open embedded zip file inside zip file without using a temporary file

Tags: go, zip

I wrote a utility for examining the contents of a zip archive, including nested zip archives.  I actually implemented this in both Perl and Go, the latter of which I did yesterday.

The one thing about this algorithm that bothers me is how it examines nested archives. In order to open the nested archive, I have to write the content of the nested archive to a temporary file on disk, and then read it in again to open the nested archive.

Particularly with the golang implementation, I would like to avoid that. I would like to be able to open the nested archive directly from memory.  I've examined the archive/zip package, and I don't see an obvious way to do this.

Comment: You may do so if you read the embedded zip into a byte buffer, and use that to open it. But you have to read it all.

Comment: [NewReader](https://pkg.go.dev/archive/zip#NewReader) does not require a file on disk, but it does require a seekable reader.  Read the contents of the nested zip to a []byte and create a  [bytes.NewReader](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes#Reader) with the []byte to get a seekable reader.

Comment: I could use a little more explanation here. I don't understand how to get a ReaderAt from a []byte.

Comment: `bytes.NewReader()` will return a reader that implements `ReaderAt()`.

Comment: Finally figured that out. It appears to be working.

Comment: Maybe using the regular File/Folder concepts but an alternate filesystem implementation like [spf13/afero#Memory-backed-storage](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/spf13/afero#readme-memory-backed-storage). You could create an in-memory filesystem and write all files and folders into that.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr if you figured it out, maybe you could answer your own question to help those coming here for an answer.